# Validate if an array contains character(s) that are not in my allowed character list

Tags: excel, vba

I got an initial code but it's not working correctly, if you guys have any suggestions on how to achieve it and make the code better (cleaner/faster) I would really appreciate it.

```
    Sub CountByError()
        
    Dim rangeArr() As Variant
    Dim xcharFlag As Boolean
    Dim tester2 As Worksheet
    Set tester2 = Worksheets("tester2")
    
    rangeArr = Worksheets("tester").Range("a2").Resize(3169, 30).Value2
    
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    
    For i = 1 To 29
      
        Select Case i
            Case 1
                For j = 1 To 3168

                    xcharFlag = False
    
                    For k = 1 To Len(rangeArr(j, i))
                        If Not Mid(Len(rangeArr(j, i)), k, 1) Like "[a-zA-Z0-9-]" Then
                            xcharFlag = True
                            If xcharFlag = True Then Exit For
                        End If
                    Next k
                    If xcharFlag = True Then
                        tester2.Range("d4") = tester2.Range("d4") + 1
                    End If 
                Next j
        End Select
    Next i
Worksheets("tester").Range("a2").Resize(3169, 30).Value2 = rangeArr
    
    End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean with *"not working correctly"*? Have you debugged the code? And why do you have this strange ` Select Case i` in the loop?

Comment: I mean it's not working as expected. It counts the input as error even if the characters in the cell is in the allowed list (alphanumeric plus hypen(-)). It's just part of a longer validation, I just decided to put it inside a Select Case instead of an If-Else. I'm stuck in this part.

Comment: What I'm trying to do here is sort of an error counter

Comment: Your `Case 1` makes that only the first row is checked - you are aware of that?

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that. This is actually up to Case 14. I am only highlighting this because once this part got resolved I think I can take care of the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always good to split the code into smaller pieces. In your case, I would suggest you move the check if a string contains invalid characters into a boolean function. That makes it much easier to test and debug.

```
Function containsInvalidChar(ByVal s As String) As Boolean
    Dim k As Long
    For k = 1 To Len(s)
        If Not Mid(s, k, 1) Like "[a-zA-Z0-9-]" Then
            containsInvalidChar = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next k
    containsInvalidChar = False    
End Function
```

Now open the immediate window and enter something like (the TRUE and FALSE is the response).

```
? containsInvalidChar("ABC")
FALSE
? containsInvalidChar("12-34 56")
TRUE
? containsInvalidChar(ActiveCell)
FALSE
```

Once you are rather sure that the function works as expected, remove the code from your nested loops and replace it with a simple call to the function:

```
 (...)
   For j = 1 To 3168
        If containsInvalidChar(rangeArr(j, i)) then
            tester2.Range("d4") = tester2.Range("d4") + 1
        End If 
   Next j
```

By this, you separate the logic how to identify an invalid string from the logic of how to deal with that situation. You could easily change the function to use regular expressions instead of the `like` (which probably would increase execution speed) without touching the rest of the code, or you could reuse the function to mark invalid words with a different color (could even be used as function in conditional formatting).

Your current check, by the way, has a superfluent `Len(` in the check.

Comment: Detailed and clear. Thank you. I needed to add another set of parenthesis in calling the function `If containsInvalidChar((rangeArr(j,i)))` else you will get ByRef type mismatch error.

Comment: C4DXYZ-SO You are right, but @BigBen's suggestion is better. I update my answer

Answer (score 0):

This is how it should work

```
Sub CountByError()
    
    Dim rangeArr() As Variant
    Dim tester2 As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    
    Set tester2 = Worksheets("tester2")
    rangeArr = Worksheets("tester").Range("a2").Resize(3169, 30).Value2
    tester2.Range("d4") = 0
    For i = LBound(rangeArr, 1) To UBound(rangeArr, 1)
        For j = LBound(rangeArr, 2) To UBound(rangeArr, 2)
            For k = 1 To Len(rangeArr(i, j))
                If Mid(rangeArr(i, j), k, 1) Like "[!a-zA-Z0-9-]" Then
                    tester2.Range("d4") = tester2.Range("d4") + 1
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next k
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

The macro may be slow and some changes to optimize the code may be useful.